# { Nodejs - Express } Client-side send request twice ! How to stop this bug

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I'm just learning nodejs but this bug kills me inside !!
My website keeps requesting twice every Post method we have. At first, I thought it was my bad in connection with mongodb but I was wrong, this happens every POST method I have on my website (except login function).

[image: Network filtering POST method]

Example: My comment function

Client-side

```
$('.commentSubmit').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let commentContent = $('#Comment').val()
    let postId = $('#input-comment').val()
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dashboard/postComment',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            postId: postId,
            comment: commentContent
        }
    })
    .done(data => {
        let htmlcomment = `
            <li class="list-group-item mt-3" id="${data._id}">
                <h6 class="card-title" >${data.Owner}
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">${data.createAt} </small></p>
                </h6>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
                <p class="card-text" >${data.content} </p>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted" style="text-align: right;">
                    <button type="button" id="commentdelete" data-id="${data._id}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm commentdelete">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </li>`

            
        $(`ul#${postId}ulul`).prepend(htmlcomment)
        document.getElementById('Comment').value = ''
    })
})
```

Server

```
router.post('/postComment', (req, res) => {
console.log('done')
req.connection.setTimeout( 1000 * 60 * 10 )
if(req.session._id) {
    if(!req.body.comment || !req.body.postId) {
        return res.render('dashboard',{errors: 'Input comment first', user: u, posts: post, comments: comment, notifs: notif})
    }
    let comment = req.body.comment
    let postId = req.body.postId
    User.findOne({_id: req.session._id})
    .then(u => {
        user = u
    })
    console.log(req.url)
    Posts.findOne({_id: postId})
    .then(p => {
        if(!p) res.send('PostID NOT Valid')
        let comment = new Comments({
            content: req.body.comment,
            Owner: user.name,
            PostId: postId
        })
        comment.save();
        return res.json(comment)
    })
} else {
    return res.redirect('/login')
}
```

})

Comment: Do you have a button with type submit? Do you also have a form submit handier in addition to your click handler?

Comment: Start by putting a `console.log()` in your client-side code that issues the POST and make sure your code isn't being called twice.  Then, put a `return` at the start of your code right after the `e.preventDefault()` and see if the form is still posted by the browser.

Comment: I am putting `console.log('clicked')` in client-side. Result in 2 click and server-side execute twice. inspect dev tool showed me every post method request twice. After did the return you told me `return console.log('test')`, It end with 2 test in console, mean it return twice

Comment: If your client-side code is executing twice, then you can start by adding `e.stopPropagation()`.  You can also switch to using an id so your `.click()` handler can only possibly target one element and not be on more than one element.

Comment: I dont know what cause this bug but it still haunted by it. :< after tried all these solutions

Comment: This means that either this `$('.commentSubmit').click(...)` is getting called twice so your event handler is installed as a duplicate or there are multiple places in the DOM hierarchy that match `$('.commentSubmit')` and the event is propagating upwards and thus getting called twice.  It would take only a few minutes to track down this problem if we had a fully reproducible case (like could see and execute and debug your whole page).  Since you're knew here, please reply to a specific person with something like `@jfriend00` in the comment - otherwise, we are not notified and will not see it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a form in your client side
and a button with .commentSubmit class.

you trap the click event and try to prevent the default behavior.
change the submit button type from submmit to button :

```
<button type="button">save</button>
```

so the button will not submit your form , but the js code will do the ajax post for you.
the prevent default will work on form.sumbit event if you trap the form.onsubmit event.

Comment: It already that button type so i am get confuse right now @@

Comment: can you post me the full client code (i nedd the html markup too) , so i can check it in my local dev env ? give me a github link or something else